# Why does the exit status differ when running `systemctl start; systemctl is-active` and `systemctl is-active` separately?

Tags: bash, command-line, exit-status

The following sequence gives me the return value of the first command, not the 2nd as I would have expected (no matter if I run the 1st command in a subshell):

```
sudo systemctl start x; sudo systemctl is-active --quiet x; echo $?;
(sudo systemctl start x); sudo systemctl is-active --quiet x; echo $?;
```

The service `x` is broken and could not be started - so he's not running. The following command, ran stand-alone, gives me a correct return value of `3` as it should be:

```
sudo systemctl is-active --quiet x; echo $?;
```

So, why am I getting the return value of the first command (`0`) when running `command; command; echo $?` instead of the return value (`3`) of the second with `echo $?`?

I'm on `GNU bash, version 4.4.12(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)`. I know, that if I split it on 2 lines, it works:

```
sudo systemctl start x;
sudo systemctl is-active --quiet x; echo $?;
```

But I need to have it as a one-liner, as I'm putting it in PHP `shell_exec()` function. And running twice `shell_exec()` has the same result as putting the commands in one line.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

When I encounter an issue like this, I tend to follow Sherlock Holmes’ mantra, and consider what is left, however implausible, once the impossible is eliminated. Of course with computers nothing is impossible, however some things are so unlikely we can ignore them at first. (This makes more sense with the original title, “`command; command; echo $?` — return value is not correct, why?”)

In this case, if

```
sudo systemctl start x; sudo systemctl is-active --quiet x; echo $?;
```

shows that `$?` is 0, that means that `systemctl is-active` really did indicate success. The fact that a separate `systemctl is-active` shows that the service isn’t active strongly suggests that there’s a race between the service and the human operator typing the commands; basically, that the service does start, to a sufficient extent for `systemctl start` to finish, and `systemctl is-active` to run and find the service active, but then the service fails, so a human-entered `systemctl is-active` finds it inactive.

Adding a short delay between `systemctl start` and `systemctl is-active` should avoid the false positive.

Answer (score 4):

Systemd brings the service up for a short time (`0.1` seconds) and then the service crashes.

Returns `3` as it should be;

```
sudo systemctl start x; sleep 0.2; sudo systemctl is-active --quiet x; echo $?;
```

Less, than `0.2` seconds, it returns `0` as it should not be:

```
sudo systemctl start x; sleep 0.1; sudo systemctl is-active --quiet x; echo $?;
```

Also if I do `systemctl start x; ps -fA | grep -i x` I see the service. If I run `ps` again after that, it's gone.

Comment: An ExecStartPost that checks whether the service is *really* up and fails if it isn't is one way to avoid this. If you maintain the source to your service and use the `sd_notify` socket to self-report startup success, even moreso. Which is to say -- it's entirely possible to make sure systemd knows when a service is in fact successfully initialized; it just takes some extra code.

Comment: +1 @CharlesDuffy for `sd_notify` information - unfortunately I do not maintain the source files. That's why it's easier to use `sleep` and wait to see what happens :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
sudo systemctl start x && sudo systemctl is-active --quiet x; echo $?;
```

The `&&` will force the system to run the commands in order, and only if the previous command completed successfully.

Comment: This does not handle the case which the user is most likely experiencing here, which is that the service _does start_, for long enough for the `is-active` to return true as well, but then dies.  As others have suggested, it would be better to insert a short delay of a a second or two between the two `systemctl` calls.

Comment: This does not work unfortunately